# How to update Status property in Notion

Tags: python, python-3.x, notion-api, notion

I have this code which works fine

```
def create_notion_page(Project_name, Status, Owner, Dates, Priority):
    try:
        url = "https://api.notion.com/v1/pages"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_token}",
            "Notion-Version": notion_version,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
        data = {
            "parent": {
                "database_id": Page
            },
            "properties": {
                "Project name": {
                    "title": [{
                        "text": {
                            "content": Project_name
                        }
                    }]
                }
        }  
            }
        
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
        return response.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

When I update remaining property it throws an error.

I need python code, pease help me fix this error

[image: Current status]

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? no one can help you if you don't include that in your question